# Working directory - solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, working-directory

How do I make the working directory the "solution directory" but not through the properties, but through the code?

I'm working in windows.

Comment: What is a "solution directory"?

Comment: I assume he means the one that has the .sln file in Visual Studio, or whatever extension it uses in the version he is using.

Comment: describe what do you want to achieve in the end.

Comment: I have a dtd file that i want to read in my solution.  I need the locatioin of the dtd file to be relative to the solution or in a constant place that doesn't change all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to find the directory that has a .sln file in it and work with it, there is no concept in C++ of such a thing as a .sln or a Makefile, or anything else really that was used in the build process to compile your project.

The concept is that you are building machine code to run without a specific runtime environment, although it may need to find other libraries at runtime.

You could hard-code the path in, or the name of the .sln file and then let your program search the filesystem for it in case it finds it, but that's just about all.

Comment: How do I make my code search the filesystem for it?  Is it easy?